# CODEIGNITER Custom redirect with only domain name in url

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting

In codeigniter I set in routes.php the default controller:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

and the roules to use the lang in url

```
$route['^(en|es|it)/(.+)$'] = "$2";
$route['^(en|es|it)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

when I write the url in the browser domain.com there is a redirect to domain.com/it/home/index

I would like that the url will be domain.com/it without /home/index

Somebody can help me?

Comment: Check .htaccess file on [this](https://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/) page. Go through code one and use rule for that or whole file code itself.